# Beanstalk Supervisor: Could not open input file: artisan

Tags: laravel-4, centos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Just been implementing this within a VM (Vagrant) and now we have uploaded it to our live server. But when trying to replicate as the VM we are getting the following error:

```
  Could not open input file: artisan
```

We have the following in the config.

```
  [program:queue]
  directory=/var/www/vhosts/website-address.co.uk/LaravelFolder
  command=php artisan queue:listen --tries=2
  autostart=true
  log_stdout=true
  log_stderr=true
  logfile=/var/www/vhosts/website-address.co.uk/LaravelFolder/app/storage/logs/supervisor.log
```

The live server is a Media Temple CentOS using nginx. Are we missing any thing or do we need to do anymore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After a bit of rework and repositioning of the config data within the file, it seems to have now worked and running, as far as what dramatically was done was nothing, just re-entering and that of the same data and position within the config file.  Still thought any thoughts would be great will mark as an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix that worked for me was to remove the directory setting with the specific config as above, into the main Directory variable within Beanstalk config file.

Answer (score 0):

change the command to :

command=php **$path_to_artisan**/artisan queue:listen --tries=2

like:

```
command=php /var/www/vhosts/website-address.co.uk/LaravelFolder/artisan queue:listen --tries=2
```

restart supervisord and it will work

the problem is that it doesn't know the 'directory' variable